Why is node:http behaving unexpectedly in Deno?
My Deno app is using the node:http package to create a server. I have noticed that the behaviour of this package seems to differ between Deno and Node, and that it does not comply with the documentation. Specifically, the value of Request.rawHeaders is not as I expect it to be.
I used the following code to inspect the value of Request.rawHeaders.
import * as http from "node:http"

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.rawHeaders)
    console.log(req.rawHeaders.toString())
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.rawHeaders))
    console.log(typeof req.rawHeaders)
    console.log(Object.keys(req.rawHeaders))
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.rawHeaders))
    console.log(Array.isArray(req.rawHeaders))
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(req.rawHeaders))
    console.log("-------------")
    res.end()
}).listen(80)

Similar code was used in Node to test the same value. After making a request to both servers, I observed the following results.



Value passed to console.log
Console result in Node
Console result in Deno




req.rawHeaders
['Host', 'localhost', 'Connection', 'keep-alive', ...]
Headers { accept: "text/html,application... see formatted value below this table.


req.rawHeaders.toString()
Host,localhost,Connection,keep-alive, ...
[object Headers]


JSON.stringify(req.rawHeaders)
["Host","localhost","Connection","keep-alive", ...]
{}


typeof req.rawHeaders
object
object


Object.keys(req.rawHeaders)
['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
[]


Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.rawHeaders)
['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
[]


Array.isArray(req.rawHeaders)
true
false


Object.getPrototypeOf(req.rawHeaders)
Object(0) []
Headers {}



Formatted value for row 1, column 3 of the table above:
Headers {
  accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  host: "localhost",
  ...
}

According to the docs on rawHeaders, the value should be an array of strings. It is not in Deno. I can't even understand what it is. A direct console.log on the value shows that it is an object with properties, but I can't access them. I tried rawHeaders['host'] and rawHeaders.host. They both return undefined. How is this possible? What is console.log doing to access the values?
What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?
Minimal Reproducible Repo
https://github.com/Tom4nt/rawHeaders-repro-repo
Additional details
I discovered this while trying to use vhost in Deno. I noticed that it does not redirect to the correct handler based on the subdomain, presumably because it can't read the host header. I'm using express instead of oak because oak requires too much boilerplate for my current requirements. Also, I don't know if I can use vhost with oak.

Deno: v2.0.4
Node: v20.17.0
OS: Windows 10 Pro build 19045.5011 (64-bit)

Can you provide a minimal reproducible repo?

Yes, it looks like a bug. (The type of the value is just Headers.)

@Ry- Thanks. I called req.rawHeaders.get("host") and it returned the correct value. Do you know why console.log returns all the details of the object while toString does not? I thought console.log just called toString...

@Tom4nt No, console.log calls Symbol.for("Deno.customInspect") or SymbolFor("nodejs.util.inspect.custom") if available

@Bergi Thank you. So the implementation of console.log is specific to the runtime. Got it.
